# How to dynamically change background-color in ASP.NET MVC core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I had an idea of changing a background color of a `div` when I click a button.
I added a string in my `'Subject'` model class  as so:

```
[NotMapped]
public string ColorHEX { get; set; }
```

And made an action inside of a controller as so:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult ChangeColor(int id)
        {
            Subject subject = _context.Subjects.Find(id);
            return View(subject);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ChangeColor(Subject subject, string color)
        {
            subject.ColorHEX = color;

            _context.Update(subject);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
```

And the post View:

```
@model Subject;

<form asp-action="ChangeColor" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="#1e1e1e;" name="color" />
</form>
```

It correctly transfers the `color` value to the controller parameter `string color`, and it stores it inside the `ColorHEX` variable.

And my idea was to implement it in an inline style of a `div` inside the `foreach` loop. Like so:

```
@model IEnumerable<EVE_A_Planner.Models.Subject>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AllTasks";
}
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center">My Tasks</h1>

    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="mySkillsBox" style="background-color: @item.ColorHEX">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div>
                            <img class="mySkillsImage" src=@item.SubjectPicture width="200">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try this, nothing happens... Any ideas how to implement this?
Thanks!

Comment: You might use a @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {... } style loop and then use "Model[i].ColorHEX"...  (you may also want a semi-colon after the color... ex: background-color: @item.ColorHEX; )

Comment: adding to @pcalkins,  add !important  to colorHex programmatically in the controller. Sometimes other css classes could override the background-color that you are trying to insert

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     [HttpPost]
>     public IActionResult ChangeColor(Subject subject, string color)
>     {
>         subject.ColorHEX = color;
>
>         _context.Update(subject);
>         _context.SaveChanges();
>         return View();// do somethings as below...
>     }
> ```

Check with your post action.

First, you should query the database to get the  latest subject data .

Second, you have two options:

1. You can return the  latest subject data to the ChangeColor view.

2.Redirect to the Index action, in the Index action, get the  latest subject data  from database, and then return to the view(In the Index View, you can implement it in an inline style of a div inside the foreach loop ).